# Magento Set Product Image Label During Import

Tags: magento

I'm trying to import product images to Magento by using

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageFile, array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false);
```

However, I can't figure out a way to set the image's label.  I've tried getting the gallery using **getMediaGallery** , manually set the value and assign it back to the product with **setMediaGallery**, but it throws an exception.

Does anyone has experience with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

After you add the image to the media gallery through this code...

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageFile, array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false);
```

...get the `media_gallery` array from the product, and then pop the latest image being added, and there you can set the label.

After that you can push it back to the images array of the `media_gallery`, here's the code:

```
$gallery = $product->getData('media_gallery');
$lastImage = array_pop($gallery['images']);
$lastImage['label'] = $image_label;
array_push($gallery['images'], $lastImage);
$product->setData('media_gallery', $gallery);
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same task a few days ago, it can be solved by extending core classes (putting them in the 'local' code pool)

in `Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php` add new parameter `$label=''` to method `addImageToMediaGallery`
and pass it to `$mediaGalleryAttribute->getBackend()->addImage($this, $file, $mediaAttribute, $move, $exclude, $label);`

in `Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php` again add new parameter `$label=''` and change `'label'    => ''` to `'label'    => $label`

HTH

Comment: I did as you explained, then checked my application were using the right classes (all right), but even if i change 'label'=>'mylabel' in function call, this does not work in Magento 1.6.0.

Comment: @D.S. That is strange, I have tested this code on EE 1.10 and it worked perfectly. I don't think it differs in this regard between editions, but perhaps CE has another method for saving labels? Did you check with xdebug? I couldn't check it right now though

Comment: @Zifus No, I've only printed currently used class names in order to assure my inherited classes are used instead of the Magento defaults... Thank you anyway for showing me how to quickly override default Magento behaviour :)

Comment: @D.S. Main thing that I've missed is that your import adapter `Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product` must pass a label to `addImageToMediaGallery` method

Comment: This is the most elegant solution. Why this isn't already implemented this way already in the core files in beyond me...

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to give a try to [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/), you can assign labels and it is super fast.